# Differentiability of $x^\alpha \sin(x^{-\beta})$ at $x = 0$

Tags: derivatives

\begin{align*}
 f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}   
      0 &  \text{ if } x=0\\
  x^\alpha \sin(x^{-\beta}) &  \text{ otherwise }
 \end{array}\right.
 \end{align*}

Determine the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which this function is differentiable at $x=0$.

I found the derivative, but I don't know what to do after...

Comment: What did you find for the derivative, and how did you find it? By the way, are there conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Yes, the conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be found. I differentiated the second function with respect to x

Comment: @kiwifruit I assume that you just used product and chain rule for the derivative? If so, that only works *away* from $0$.

Comment: By differentiating the function, you have presupposed what you were trying to prove. Or else you have found a result for $x>0$, where the differentiability is not in question.

Comment: Yes, I found the derivative only for the second part using the product & chain rule. Not sure what to do with the 0

Comment: @JasonZimba I see! What would the right approach be then to prove differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Remember the definition of the derivative at $0$:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^{\alpha - 1} \sin\left(x^{-\beta}\right)$$

Now the sine function oscillates as the input goes to zero or to infinity, so the only way the limit can possibly exist is if the term $x^{\alpha - 1}$ kills the oscillation by tending to zero. This suggests that you might want to consider cases based on $\alpha > 1$, $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha < 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Well, it seems like only $\alpha >1$ would give the necessary result. But are there any conditions for $\beta$?

Comment: @kiwifruit Consider the case $\alpha = 1$; a condition on $\beta$ is necessary there.

Comment: So if $\alpha=1$, we get the oscillating sin. Then must we force it to be some specific value like 1?

Comment: @kiwifruit Not quite. The question is whether $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left(x^{-\beta}\right)$ exists: Again, considering cases of $\beta$ will be helpful.

Comment: It does not exist of $\beta=0$, but it will be some value for the other cases?

Comment: @kiwifruit If $\beta = 0$, then you're considering $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1)$.

Comment: So it would be a fixed value in this case, and sin(0) in all other cases?

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify some cases. I came too late
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^\alpha sin(x^{-\beta})-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}x^{\alpha-1} sin(x^{-\beta})$$
Then is differentiable if the previous limit exists.
We have the case $\alpha>1$, $\alpha=1$ $\alpha>1$ and the cases for $\beta=0$,$\beta>0$, $\beta<0$

$\alpha>1$ $\beta=0$ clearly converges to $0$

$\alpha<1$ $\beta=0$ clearly diverges

$\alpha=1$ $\beta=0$ clearly converges

$\alpha>1$ $\beta<0$ converges to $0$

$\alpha<1$ $\beta<0$ we have a limit of the form:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{sin(x^{-\beta})}{x^{1-\alpha}}$$
Take $u=x^{-\beta}$ then $x^{1-\alpha}=u^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}}$
$$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{sin(u)}{u^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}}}$$
Here if $\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}<1$ it converges and in another case diverges

$\alpha=1$ $\beta<0$ clearly converges